# In Google Analytics, is there any way to exclude traffic from a source, but only when the traffic uses a certain Service Provider?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to do some analysis in Google Analytics and discovered that there is a particular bot that is sending a ton of 'fake' traffic to my site. I'd like to exclude this traffic from the analysis. It comes from a certain source (the same one every time) and is always on 1 of 4 Service Providers. I have isolated the traffic with the following segment:

```
INCLUDE "Service Provider" Matches RegExp "W|X|Y|Z"
AND
INCLUDE "Source" Matches RegExp "nameOfSource.com"
```

^^That returns the exact traffic I would like to exclude. So one would assume that when I set the INCLUDEs to EXCLUDEs it would give me what I need (everything except that segment). Instead, it excludes all traffic from nameOfSource.com.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could successfully exclude that traffic, without removing the legitimate traffic from nameOfSource.com as well?

Thanks in Advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics has filters for this purpose.
First of all create another profile so you have 2 profiles an unfiltered profile with all your data and create a a second profile and on that profile add the filters you want.
You can find this under the admin section in your GA account.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't believe a filter would be able to handle this level of specificity any more than advanced segments could. Also, all my data has already been collected so I am trying to work with what I've got. The problem is not with the data we've collected, but rather the logic that Advanced Segments allow.

Answer (score 0):

AND statements in Advanced Segment are not cumulative but they are not cumulative but they run one after the other.

You can do it with Advanced filter.

1. on field A extract "nameOfSource.com" from source
2. on field B extract "W|X|Y|Z" from ISP
3. output A+B to a custom var

Then you can use a second filter to exclude trafic with this custom var, or use an Advanced segment on it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This won't help for historical data, but it great to know for the future. I'd like to confirm with you that this would exclude only nameOfSource.com referrals that are using ISP W|X|Y|Z, but maintains the legitimate traffic from each respective field? Also, would the OutPut To field be "Custom Field 1"? Finally, I assume the 4 radio buttons would be... Field A Required=Yes, Field B Required=Yes, Override Output Field=No, Case Sensitive=no?   THANK YOU!!